# TFS 2013 - Documents Folder is missing

Tags: tfs

I'm working with TFS 2013 and I don't see the documents folder
Any Idea how to add this shared folder?

https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC687893.png

Comment: Do you have Sharepoint installed and configured? If so, do **you** have permission to access it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Sharepoint configured to integrate with your team project to get the documents node. You can install SharePoint on the TFS server, or integrate with your corporate nodes.

http://nakedalm.com/integrate-sharepoint-2013-with-team-foundation-server-2012/

To be honest I believe this to be more hassle than it is worth.